# Global theme with TypeScript/React/Material-UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm following [the official tutorial](https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/#advanced) to create global theme for my app.

My root component is supposed to provide global theme:

```
const themeInstance = {
  backgroundColor: 'cadetblue'
}

render (
    <ThemeProvider theme={themeInstance}>
      <ChildComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>,
    rootNode
)
```

But I can't seem to get my child component to apply the theme:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => {
  childComp: {
    backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor
  }
})

const ChildComponent: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles()
  return (
    <div className={classes.childComp}>I'm a div</div>
  )
}
```

`<ChildComponent />` is getting rendered un-styled.

It looks to be a types mismatch issue of some sort as when I started to play around with types of `theme` parameter, the browser has rendered the expected output (`<ChildComponent />` div with `background-color: cadetblue`) for split second than failed with error.

Any help to figure out where did I go wrong way are quite appreciated.

Live sandbox can be found [over here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vzln9r?file=childComponent.tsx).

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to type your custom theme. By default `makeStyle` will use default theme type which has the following signature:

```js
export interface Theme {
  shape: Shape;
  breakpoints: Breakpoints;
  direction: Direction;
  mixins: Mixins;
  components?: Components;
  palette: Palette;
  shadows: Shadows;
  spacing: Spacing;
  transitions: Transitions;
  typography: Typography;
  zIndex: ZIndex;
  unstable_strictMode?: boolean;
}
```

As you can see, it doesn't have `backgroundColor` property. You need to update the Theme definition by using *module augmentation* to make typescript stop complaining about the incorrect theme type.

```js
import { Theme } from "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme";
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

declare module "@material-ui/styles" {
  interface DefaultTheme extends MyTheme {}
}

declare module "@material-ui/core/styles/createMuiTheme" {
  interface ThemeOptions extends MyTheme {}
}

export interface MyTheme extends Theme {
  backgroundColor: string;
}

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  backgroundColor: "red"
});

export { theme };
```

In your component

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  childComp: {
    backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor
  }
}));
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64294250/global-theme-with-typescript-react-material-ui]

Answer (score 1):

This happens to me often. Try the following:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  childComp: {
    backgroundColor: theme.backgroundColor
  }
}));
```

Note the `( )`

Live sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-e7vw8s?file=childComponent.tsx

Comment: @ZChu I believe the correct way is to setup a `palette` in your global style and access it everywhere else. I'm not sure why `backgroundColor` is not accessible via the default `Theme` type but you could just `(theme: any)` to get around it until you eventually setup the palette.

Comment: @ZChu Ahh, I noticed you did make a custom global theme. You should follow https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/